# Custom home directory leads to permission error when logging in with "su -l"

Tags: permissions, users, home

When I create a user with a different home directory on a Linux system like this:

```
# useradd "svcjohn" -U -r -m -d "/var/lib/svcjohn"
```

I get an error like this:

```
# su -l svcjohn
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/svcjohn’: Permission denied
```

```
$ pwd
/var/lib/svcjohn
```

Yes, I can log in successfully, but why am I getting this error even though I changed the user's home folder?

Comment: Since it is some command trying to create it on login, then you need to look through `/etc/profile*`, `/etc/bash*`, `/etc/skel.d/*`, `/var/lib/svcjohn/.??*` etc to find where that command is being run from & to alter it as required.

Comment: System accounts (created with `useradd -r`) usually are not used for logging in interactively (at least not with a _login shell_), which is why using `useradd -r` will not create a home directory by default.  Are you sure you want to create a system user, or alternatively, are you sure you need to open a _login shell_ when you switch to that system user?

Comment: @Kusalananda but the error is about a different dir, not the home dir set by the command, which apparently already exists based on the `pwd` command shown by the OP. Also, they are using `-m` which should create the dir anyway, according to the `-r` section of `man useradd`.

Comment: @terdon Yes, but I want to determine whether this is a "Don't do that then" issue or something that needs to be tracked down, explained, and possibly fixed.